# Creating reusable library for ionic projects

Tags: firebase, ionic-framework

We have built an analytics package that uses angularfire2 as a way to interact with firebase db. rest of the code is just regular typescript files more like utility classes.

is there a way to make it reusable by simply somehow referring to an existing ionic project.

Even if it's possible my other concern is that the host ionic project may have its on angularfire config. So would the imported analytic project lib will be able to keep its on fire config and connection in isolation?

Please advise how to achieve this reusability?